# Remove element from jsonb array with postgres

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a table in postgres that contains column of type jsonb, i used to save in this field array of jsons in this format.

```
post_id                             |questions                                                                                                                                                                                      |
------------------------------------|---------------------------------------
70071d97-06a8-401f-abfc-20ddada4f402|[{"question": "TEST QUESTION", "transaction_id": "ac547b52-72f3-444e-800c-46aaa48855a5"}, {"question":   "TEST QUESTION", "transaction_id": "ac547b52-72f3-444e-800c-46aaa48855ab"}]|
```

i want to delete an item in that list based on the transaction_id.

```
post_id                             |questions                                                                                                                                                                                 |
------------------------------------|---------------------------------------
70071d97-06a8-401f-abfc-20ddada4f402|[{"question": "TEST QUESTION", "transaction_id": "ac547b52-72f3-444e-800c-46aaa48855a5"}]|
```

I have tried couple of methods but None worked, i tried

```
select questions - '{"question": "TEST QUESTION", "transaction_id": "ac547b52-72f3-444e-800c-46aaa48855a5"}' from posts where post_id = '70071d97-06a8-401f-abfc-20ddada4f402';
```

Comment: please show us what you tried so far

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[step-by-step demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=14eed8d13eb761ce4d8e5d890f3f1d2c)

```
UPDATE posts p
SET questions = data
FROM (
    SELECT
        questions,
        jsonb_agg(elems.value) AS data                       -- 3
    FROM
        posts,
        jsonb_array_elements(questions) elems                -- 1
    WHERE                                                    -- 2
        not (elems.value ->> 'transaction_id' = 'ac547b52-72f3-444e-800c-46aaa48855a5')
    GROUP BY questions
) s
WHERE s.questions = p.questions;
```

1. Expand array into one row per array element
2. Filter out the element to be deleted
3. Group all remaining element into a new array

Comment: If it's important to preserve the original order in the array, you can use `with ordinality`: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=fd5a1464557122f6f06248df0e9be192

Comment: Thanks for your response it was really helpfull, i made a slightly modified version of your original code, juste in case of we delete all items in that array we cant add more items to it so i made sure that if its null i replace it with empty array.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for S-Man response . i was able to acheive what exactly i wanted.

```
update edz_posts set questions =     
(SELECT
    '[]'::jsonb || jsonb_agg(elems.value)
FROM
    edz_posts,
    jsonb_array_elements(questions) elems 
where post_id = :post_id and universe_id=:universe_id
and not (elems.value ->> 'transaction_id' = :transaction_id)
group by questions)
where post_id = :post_id and universe_id=:universe_id
;
update edz_posts set questions = '[]'::jsonb where questions is null ;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my upgrade of the *S-Man/a_horse_with_no_name* examples for updating **room** table with **uid** identifier & **message** jsonb column.
This way if there are no messages left, empty [] is inserted instead.

**Room**

| uid | messages |
| --- | --- |
| a0eebc99-9c0b-4ef8-bb6d-6bb9bd380a11 | { 'message_uid': 'test_id', text: 'hello' } |

```
do $$
declare
    filtered jsonb;
BEGIN

SELECT
    messages,
    jsonb_agg(elems.value order by elems.idx) AS data
FROM
    room,
    jsonb_array_elements(messages) with ordinality as elems(value, idx)
WHERE
    not (elems.value ->> 'text' = 'Hello2') and
    uid = 'a0eebc99-9c0b-4ef8-bb6d-6bb9bd380a11'
GROUP BY messages
INTO filtered;

UPDATE room p
SET messages = COALESCE(filtered, '[]'::jsonb)
WHERE uid = 'a0eebc99-9c0b-4ef8-bb6d-6bb9bd380a11';
end $$
```

UPDATE: better version using a function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION filteredJsonB(messages jsonb, not_key TEXT, not_value TEXT)
   RETURNS jsonb 
  AS
$$
    DECLARE 
        filtered jsonb;
    BEGIN
        SELECT
            jsonb_agg(elems.value ORDER BY elems.idx) AS DATA
        FROM
            jsonb_array_elements(messages) WITH ordinality AS elems(VALUE, idx)
        WHERE
            NOT (elems.value ->> not_key = not_value)
        GROUP BY messages
        INTO filtered;
        RETURN filtered;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

do $$
BEGIN

  UPDATE room p
  SET messages = COALESCE(filteredJsonB(p.messages, 'text', 'Hello2'), '[]'::jsonb)
  WHERE uid = 'a0eebc99-9c0b-4ef8-bb6d-6bb9bd380a11';
END $$
```